# got the .equals() on incompatible types problem, how do i make my ArrayList <Point> and point compatible and the answer into an boolean

Tags: java, arraylist, point

im making a Snake game and dont want my cherry to spawn inside the snakes body but when i want to use equals to figure out if it inside it or not it cant cause they are not compatible. is it any way to make them compatible or do i have to make it in another way [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyCla.png)

```
public boolean collisionCheck1 (Point cherry){


     if (snakeParts.equals(cherry)){
     return true;

     }
     else 
         return false;
 }
```

this is the checking part snakeParts is the arraylist and cherry is the point

Comment: What is `snakeParts`? I'm guessing it's a collection, and you want to do something like `snakeParts.contains(cherry)'.

Comment: snakeParts is the array in which the snake parts is getting stored in so all the information about the snakes tail is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` is a class from `java.util package`, which is a child class of `java.util.Collection` interface. It is used to hold a list(to understand you can assume as an array of objects but they are not actually the same) of objects of any type if you don't specify the generic type.

In your case, `snakeParts` is an `ArrayList<Point>` object and which contains a list of Point type objects (not just one Point object).

But here, `snakeParts.equals(cherry)` you are trying to compare `ArrayList` type object to `Point` type object.

I am unable to understand what actually you trying to do, but if you want to compare you have to do something like this.

```
snakeParts.get(i).equals(Point class object)
```

where `i` is the index of `ArrayList`.

To check whether `snakeParts ArrayList` contains `cherry` object or not you can use `contains(your object)` method of `java.util.List` interface like this

`snakeParts.contains(cherry)`

It returns true if `snakeParts ArrayList` contains `cherry` Point object otherwise returns false.

Comment: what i am trying to do is figure out if any of the values in snakeParts is on the same cordinates as the cherry. for example lets say i just took a cherry then its going to respawn at a random spot. what im trying to do here is if the new cherry spawns on one of the spots where the snake already is i want it to send back the boolean telling me that so it can choose a new spot for the cherry

Comment: you can use .contains(your object)  method of java.util.List interface like this snakeParts.contains(cherry) .
It returns true if "snakeParts ArrayList" contains "cherry" Point  object otherwise returns false.

Comment: thanks the thing you commented worked perfectly i dont know if you can edit it in so others can see in your original answer but i marked that as solution atleast

Comment: I am happy that it worked for you and also you have accepted the answer. 
Yeah, I have edited the original answer.